# Spring DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an application that uses Spring with the following configuration

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/*" location="/" />
<context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
```

And this is the whole web.xml file

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The application runs very well on localhost:8080/web, but I want to change it to localhost:8080/web/rest and for doing that I tried to change the url pattern from

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using apache?

Comment: yes, I am using apache, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your change you are filtering the URL intercepted by the DispatcherServlet to be  only those starting with `/rest` and not all `/` as before, so you are just reducing the number of URL handled by Spring, not changing mappings. This is not what you want, I am afraid is not possible to "move down one level" (from `/web` to `/web/rest`) a java web application with some web.xml configuration, you should rewrite your mappings in Spring configuration (what was `/` is now `/rest`, what was `/foo` is now `/rest/foo`).